# Pass scroll value as percentage as argument, calculate distance between two points?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

My code:

```
var vert = $(this).scrollTop();
function scrollBetween(startPoint, endPoint, name){
        var progressNumber;

        progressNumber = (1 / (endPoint - startPoint)) * (vert - startPoint);
        if (progressNumber >= 0 && progressNumber <= 1) {
            name.progress(progressNumber);
        }
        else if(progressNumber < 0) {
            name.progress(0);
        }
        else if(progressNumber > 1) {
            name.progress(1);
        }
    }
```

An example of it being called:

```
scrollBetween(300, 700, anim1);
```

So as it is currently written, I have two points in pixels being passed to my function. What I can't figure out is how to convert these points to percentages of the total viewport instead. So I want to achieve this:

```
scrollBetween(2%, 15%, anim1);
```

But I keep getting errors with the various approaches I have tried. I know I can't pass it like ^ above but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the % instead of pixels.

I want to use % instead of px as I want the page to remain responsive.

Thanks.

Comment: Why send through '%',  Just get the width of the progress and calculate the percentage yourself? startPoint=(width / 100) * startPoint;

Comment: I'm trying to work it out in relation to the viewport height. So would it be instead something like scrollBetween(2,15,anim1) and in my function then, startPoint=(height/100) * startPoint and endPoint=(height/100) * endPoint?

Comment: this sounds correct =] let me know if you need any help

Comment: Thank you @krisph, I will try this and will comment to let you know how it goes!

Comment: @krisph this appears to have worked, thanks for your help with my terrible maths :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@krisph helped me with this, I did the following to get responsive percentage values:

```
var vert = $(this).scrollTop();
var docHeight = $(document).height();

function scrollBetween(startPoint, endPoint, name){
    var progressNumber;

    startPoint = (docHeight/100) * startPoint;
    endPoint = (docHeight/100) * endPoint;


    progressNumber = (1 / (endPoint - startPoint)) * (vert - startPoint);
    if (progressNumber >= 0 && progressNumber <= 1) {
        name.progress(progressNumber);
    }
    else if(progressNumber < 0) {
        name.progress(0);
    }
    else if(progressNumber > 1) {
        name.progress(1);
    }
}

scrollBetween(2, 15, anim1);
```